# Switch currently connected proxy user

Tags: windows-7, macos, proxy

Is there a way to change the currently connected proxy user?

I am sitting with a situation where I need to change proxy users every now and again.

What I want to achieve is to connect to the proxy with user1 and then on the fly disconnect user1 and connect with user2.

So far this has been a struggle as every time I want to change users I need to get the one user disabled and enable the other one.

This is not only an issue on the Win7 machines, but also the Mac's.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Firefox, you can use the Addon [FoxyProxy](https://addons.mozilla.org/de/firefox/addon/foxyproxy-standard/), which allows you to use multiple proxy connections with different Users.

Comment: When you say different users, do you mean different proxy users or different windows users?

Comment: Different proxy users.